# How to delete ip route by URL?

Tags: linux, networking, iproute

After running a (probably broken) openvpn script, I have an IP route table where one entry is a URL:

```
# netstat -r                                        
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp58s0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp58s0
google.com      10.0.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 wlp58s0
```

How can I delete this last row? The regular way throws an error:

```
# ip route del google.com
Error: any valid prefix is expected rather than "google.com".
```

I'm on gentoo linux, if that matters.

Comment: Adding the -n flag to netstat will remove any confusion.

Comment: Oh, so simple, thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry `google.com` is not a URL; it's a domain name, or possibly a host name. (It could be part of a URL, though.)

If you use `netstat -rn` you will get IP addresses instead of names in that first column. From there you can delete the route - again by reference to its network and subnet addressing.

```
netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         server.roaima   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
google.com      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth1

netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.2     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
216.58.198.174  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth1

route delete -host 216.58.198.174
```

You can also do this with the newer `ip route`, which lists routes only with IP addresses. Use `ip route del` to delete the unwanted entry.